# C# variable that can't be changed but need to be initialed in the constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, constants, final

I need an attribute that can't be changed after initialisation in the constructor

somthing like this:

```
private const string banknr;

public ClassName(string banknr)
{
    this.banknr = banknr;
    //from now on "banknr" can't be changed something like a final or const
}
```

but it just doesn't work, I realy don't understand

Comment: Check `readonly` keyword https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

Comment: "it just doesn't work" is never enough information. In future, please provide the exact error message in your question. In this case, you want `readonly` instead of `const` - `const` is for compile-time constants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's precisely what the [`readonly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) keyword does.

```
private readonly string banknr;

public ClassName(string banknr)
{
    this.banknr = banknr;
    //from now on "banknr" can't be changed something like a final or const
}
```

readonly variables can be set in a constructor, but can not be changed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not at my IDE so I just copied and pasted his constructor. This is, of course, assuming that strienter and hereng are actually defined types

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad ["For an instance field, in the instance constructors of the class that contains the field declaration"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx), so they can be in both, as long as they are not static.  Since the question is about setting in the constructor, the read only should not be static.

Comment: @Trisped Yes I was fast typing the code in the IDE and didn't notice I was marking the field as both readonly and static.

Answer (score 3):

If you want value can't be touched after initialization you can use `readonly` keyword:

```
public class Class2
{
    public readonly string MyProperty;
    public Class2()
    {
        MyProperty = "value";
    }
}
```

> **[readonly (C# Reference):](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx)**
>
> You can assign a value to a readonly field only in the following
>   contexts:
>
> - When the variable is initialized in the declaration.
> - For an instance field, in the instance constructors of the class that contains the field declaration, or for a static field, in the
>     static constructor of the class that contains the field declaration.
>     These are also the only contexts in which it is valid to pass a
>     readonly field as an out or ref parameter.

If you want the value can't be touched out of your class you can use a private setter in a property:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string MyProperty { get; private set; }

    public Class1()
    {
        MyProperty = "value";
    }
}
```

Comment: MyProperty can also be set in any other method belonging to Class1, not just in the constructor of Class1.

Comment: You need to add a references for the content you copied.

Comment: @Trisped reference added.

Answer (score 1):

You want readonly instead of const. The difference can be found at http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/63416. Summary here:

- const: only initialized at declaration
- readonly: can be initialized at declaration or constructor